# How to get type of a protobuf message from a raw protobuf buffer and the .proto files?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, dump, protobuf-python

Let's say that I have dumped a protobuf message to a file called packet.bin .

Let's also say that I have the .proto files which describes many message types of which one is the type of the dumped message.

How can I determine which type of message the original message was with the use of the .proto files in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly: you cannot. It is usually expected that you *know externally* (via documentation, or service definition such as gRPC) what type you are receiving.

You *can* usually figure it out manually though; you could try all of them and see which works the best, or you could look at the payload via `protoc`'s raw decode mode (or use tools such as https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode), and again: try to figure it out from there.